# Register dbus object and interface with low level API

Tags: c, api, dbus

How does one register an object, interface, and methods on the session bus using the [D-Bus low-level public API](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBus.html)?

I've read many things about DBus and the best resource that I could find for doing what I currently want was [Using the DBUS C API](http://www.matthew.ath.cx/misc/dbus) which describes how to request a name on the bus (among other things) and I've done that successfully but I'm unable to call a method on it and when I view it with [D-Feet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/d-feet/), there are no objects listed under the name I created.  This leads me to think that there are additional steps to register an object, interface, and methods that aren't in the aforementioned guide (unless I missed something even after reading it a dozen times).

I'm confident in my ability to call methods using the low-level public API because I've successfully used it to call DBus methods exposed by off-the-shelf applications.

Please note that I am not interested in any [DBus Bindings](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/).  Thanks

Comment: [dbus.c - VideoLAN](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/modules/control/dbus/dbus.c) looks extremely promising as far as a non-trivial example goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the question I think. I believe that the reason that I couldn't call the method that I created was that I didn't have a leading slash in my `path` argument of the method call DBus message. As in:

`/com/example/whatever` correct

`com/example/whatever` incorrect

The guide I referenced in the question has the minimum requirements to do it. I believe that the reason that I couldn't see the method in D-feet is because it relies on introspection method calls, which I did not implement.